# How to add edges to object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, wireframe

I just started using three.js to make basic animations and need some help to draw edges to figures (boxes). So to do that I found a way that was setting to "true" the "wireframe" property of the THREE.MeshBasicMaterial when creating the boxes. Unfortunately it does not work for me because I don't want to display the diagonal lines of each face of the boxes.

Then I found an alternative to it that was using the THREE.EdgesHelper class that shows the edges as I want but I have another problem with it.

The thing is that I need to change the position of the faces of some boxes and kept the edges updated with this changes but the edges does not do that.

```
const cubeWidth = 3;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(cubeWidth, cubeWidth, 20);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const edge = new THREE.EdgesHelper(cube, 0x000000);
```

Then I update the frontal face of each boxes on render function:

```
cubes.forEach(function(cube) {
 const geometry = cube.children[0].geometry;

 geometry.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
  if(v.z > 0) v.x -= 3;
 });

 geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
});
```

I made a jsfiddle that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mauro98/wf20tmhu/139/

Could you give me any suggestion on how to perform what I want?
I've been looking for a solution but can't find it yet.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The helper isn't designed to work beyond bufferGeometry which is immutable.

EDIT new fiddle and code. Changed the code to handle placing the edgeHelper on the scene and tracking it for removal in userData.

https://jsfiddle.net/uuzcmn99/

```
widget.onSliderChange = function() {
    const cubes = widget.cubeMatrix.children;
  cubes.forEach(function(cube) {
    console.log(cube);
    const geometry = cube.geometry;
    geometry.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
        if(v.z > 0) v.x -= 3;
    });
    cube.scale.set(.5,.5,.5);
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    console.log(cube.userData, widget.scene);
    cube.userData.edgeHelper.geometry.dispose();
    cube.userData.edgeHelper.material.dispose();
    widget.scene.remove(cube.userData.edgeHelper);
    const edge = new THREE.EdgesHelper(cube, 0x000000);
    edge.material.linewidth = 1.5;
    cube.userData.edgeHelper = edge;
    widget.scene.add(edge);
  });
};
```

Comment: Be careful! (1) The helper must be added a child of the scene directly. (2) You must properly `dispose()` of objects when you remove them.

Comment: What is the risk of adding a helper to a child of the scene rather than the scene? Do you have an example of a dispose of a helper?

Comment: (1) The risk is the helper will not render correctly when the mesh is transformed. Try it in your fiddle. (2) https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_test_memory.html.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley I recoded, added a new fiddle, with cleanup and proof of mesh transformation working with edgeHelper. Hopefully this is  abetter answer.